# Why do I need always set permissions to the new files/directories?

Tags: permissions

I've installed postgress, I followed a tutorial how to install it on Ubuntu, and one step required to change the config file, which requires permissions to be set.

Whenever I create a bash script, I need a `sudo chown +x` to the script file in order to run it.

Is there a way to set these permissions by default to make our life easier?

Comment: Can you add an example of what you have to do to the question?

Comment: More details of what exactly you mean would be helpful.  Are you using a native (posix compatible) file system? that can store the information permanently?  How are you mounting them? (your method could force rules on the mount that overrides saved) etc... We can only guess without you providing specifics.

Comment: I've edited your question for clarity, but the file system is indeed missing.  Which one are you using? EXT4? NTFS?

Comment: I would advice to keep doing this; it is part of the basic level of security: you purposely set the executable permission to a script. If executable would be the default you can create security related problems.

Comment: You can do it with Geany. Click Build, Set Build Commands, Independent Commands, and chmod +x "%f"

Comment: Personally, I use a custom bash script with vim whenever I create a new file that automagically does a chmod +x and loads a pre-defined header depending on the file type.